# nginx proxy subdirectory to subdomain on same machine

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using the docker image from [linuxserver called swag](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/swag) which contains an nginx reverse proxy and a Let's encrypt certbot. Quite some dockerized apps are not designed to be accessed via subdirectory proxying but instead need to be proxied to a subdomain (because otherwise js and css files are requested from the domain, not the subdirectory).

My goal is to make a service at 1.test.example.com available at example.com/1

The config for the subdomain looks like this and works fine:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name 1.test.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    # some app
    location / {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://172.2.0.2:1234/;
    }
}
```

My try for proxying to the subdomain looks like this but doesn't work as my browser returns "400 Bad request":

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    # proxy to some app
    location /1/ {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass https://1.test.example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host 1.test.example.com;
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to do this using proxy_pass and without using rewrite?

Comment: You will need another `server` block - this time for `example.com`, where you should put the `location /1/` block.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I already have this block; it's the second code block. I'll edit the question to clarify this